# How to get number's arguments(length) while passing inside back tick

Tags: javascript

I got a scenario where I'm passing number of arguments inside back tick and i need to find out the 
length but every time I'm getting one. I do understand back tick do string concatenation but still i 
need some way to find the length. Here Is the example

```
var fn = (...args) => {
    console.log(args.length);
};

fn(`'mon', 'tue', 'wed'`);
```

Comment: Why are you including the backticks? ``'mon', 'tue', 'wed'`` makes it a single parameter

Comment: It's because you pass only one argument in `fn` and it's a string with back tick. What result are you expected?

Comment: You're passing a single string to `fn`. So, the number will always be `1`. I'm not sure why you use backticks but you cannot get anything else from that one argument.

Comment: there's 1 because its a string, your need to parse it, which is trivial with `.split(', ').length`.. edit no actually there's problems with split

Answer (score 0):

You are using backticks. Just delete them and pass more strings in the function:

```js
var fn = (...args) => {
    console.log(args.length);
};

fn('mon', 'tue', 'wed');
```

Through the `...args` you are telling the function that you can pass multiple parameters into the function.

Answer (score 0):

If the format is guaranteed to be comma-separated, you can split the first argument by comma.

```
var fn = (...args) => {
    console.log(args[0].split(',').length);
};

fn(`'mon', 'tue', 'wed'`); // 3
```

As mentioned by other pals, it is probably not the best way to pass arguments, but just in case the function is being called by an entity that you cannot control, this should work with this specific format.

You can also remove the spread operator `...` and use it like this

```
var fn = (args) => {
    console.log(args.split(',').length);
};

fn(`'mon', 'tue', 'wed'`); // 3
```

Comment: No, I know this way but i have some other need where back tick would be there, Now let say u have something like var fn = (...args) => { console.log(args.length); }; var a = 'mon'; var b = 'tue'; fn(${a} ${b}, mon); - In this case delimiter is white space and ',' so function should not depend on delimiter –

Comment: If the function should always take a string that contains the arguments in it, there is no possible way to split it without knowing the separator. You may try to use regex for the most common ones, but this depends on the existence of a specific structure in the string.

Answer (score 0):

As you are passing single argument, no need to use spread opearator. You can get string in single argument.

```js
var fn = (str) => {
  const funArgs = str.split(",")
  console.log(funArgs.length);
};

fn(`'mon', 'tue', 'wed'`);
```

Spread operator can be used to convert arguments to an array. If you want to use spread in any way, you can do it like:

```js
var fn = (...arr) => {
  console.log(arr.length);
};

fn('mon', 'tue', 'wed');
```

Comment: No, I know this way but i have some other need where back tick would be there, Now let say u have something like var fn = (...args) => {
 console.log(args.length);
};
var a = 'mon';
var b = 'tue';
fn(`${a} ${b}, mon`); - In this case delimiter is white space and ',' so function should not depend on delimiter

Comment: Then you can use the first approach in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing only one argument, i.e the string `'mon', 'tue', 'wed'` so you're getting exactly what you should.
Use `String.prototype.split` to split you string by the ','.
Also, spreading the arguments is useless in your case, as you have just one argument.